# Grid View in ASP.NET pictures

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have got a problem with GridView because I do not understand how can I add pictures.

This code was imported by database (in GridView):

Name      id

Robert     1

Robert     2

Robert     3

In designer: I clicked the GridView -> add new column -> Choose a field type -> ImageField

Header text -> "images"

Data field -> empty

Url Format String -> empty

I want to take data id from my second column in GridView and later put it in the third column --img src="id.jpg"-- this example can help me understand GridView. Can you help me?

I will try explain better:

```
EXAMPLE A:<asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" 
InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />

EXAMPLE B:<asp:ImageField HeaderText="picture" DataField="img src="id from EXAMPLE A.jpg""></asp:ImageField>
```

Comment: [Take a look at this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx)

Comment: I know this website but this is not the same because I have got data in GridView but here you have example how put data to Gridview this I know but my question look very simple but I think it is difficult. I need pictures in existing data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to use the `DataImageUrlFormatString` property and ending up having your `ImageField` like

```
<asp:ImageField 
        HeaderText="picture" 
        DataImageUrlField="id" 
        DataImageUrlFormatString="{0}.jpg" />
```

Comment: Good answer but I have got question to this is it possible to put for example DataImageUrlField="Select images_link from users Wher id =id" ?

Comment: sure it is! you have 2 options to accomplish that, either you get that when requesting info for your `gridview` for example, that's a `INNER JOIN` in your select, or you can ask the database that for each row. I would always go for the first one as it's just one db call...